# Is there a way to cast from 'String' to 'KType'?

Tags: kotlin

Simply, I want a function like:

```
fun <T> convert(val foo: String, fooT: KType) : T {
    ...?
}
```

For `Int`, it would return `foo.toInt()`, for `Double`, `foo.toDouble()`, and to some unknown type, just throw an exception. I think it's not so hard to create my own switch statement for the types I expect, but out of curiosity - is there a way already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Recommended way

Unfortunately, there's no easy generic way because we're not dealing with casts, but method calls. This would be my approach:

```
fun <T> convert(str: String, type: KType) : T {

    val result: Any = when (type.jvmErasure)
    {
        Long::class -> str.toLong()
        Int::class -> str.toInt()
        Short::class -> str.toShort()
        Byte::class -> str.toByte()
        ...
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("'$str' cannot be converted to $type")
    }

    return result as T // unchecked cast, but we know better than compiler
}
```

Usage:

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
fun main() {

    val int = convert<Int>("32", typeOf<Int>())

    println("converted: $int")
}
```

Instead of a `KType` parameter, you could also use a `Class<T>` and make the function reified, so it can be called as `convert<Int>("32")` or even `"32".toGeneric<Int>()`.

---

## Hardcore way

While there is no *easy* way, it *is* possible to access the type using heavy reflection and relying on implementation details. For this, we can extract the type name from the `KType` object, find an extension method (in a different class) that matches, and call it using reflection.

We have to use `to*OrNull()` instead of `to*()`, because the latter is inline and won't be found by reflection. Also, we need to resort to Java reflection -- at this time, Kotlin reflection throws `UnsupportedOperationException` for the types involved.

I do not recommend this in productive code, as it's inefficient and can break with future standard library versions, but it's a nice experiment:

```
fun convert(str: String, type: KType): Any {
    val conversionClass = Class.forName("kotlin.text.StringsKt") 
    // here, the to*OrNull() methods are stored
    // we effectively look for static method StringsKt.to*OrNull(String)

    val typeName = type.jvmErasure.simpleName
    val funcName = "to${typeName}OrNull" // those are not inline

    val func = try {
        conversionClass.getMethod(funcName, String::class.java) // Java lookup
    } catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Type $type is not a valid string conversion target")
    }

    func.isAccessible = true      // make sure we can call it
    return func.invoke(null, str) // call it (null -> static method)
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("'$str' cannot be parsed to type $type")
}
```

Comment: Very nice - the first one is what I'm actually doing now (though I just had it return `Any` as opposed to having the caller specify a type). I am using reflection in the caller of `convert` - basically getting a result from an API call and constructing an object based on the types in the object's constructor, but nothing that I think relies on implementation details.